# How do you use an OnClickListener in a recycler view?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

What i'm basically trying to do is make the objects that show up in the recycler view clickable to a certain TextView id because i'm making a program that shows an album cover and its title next to it in a list. I need to be able to click on each one of the boxes that the recycler view makes and have a TextView pop up with the other information (author, published date, hit songs, etc) when its clicked on and then a back button (if possible) to go back to the album list. I've been looking at this for hours and cant figure out how to make an OnclickListener work for it. If you know how or have any suggestions id be glad to hear them. Thank you!

```
package com.albumlist.albumlist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private AlbumData[] itemsData;

    public MyAdapter(AlbumData[] itemsData){
        this.itemsData = itemsData;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private TextView txtViewTitle;
        private ImageView imgViewIcon;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);
            txtViewTitle = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.album_title);
            imgViewIcon = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.album_icon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {

        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.data_layout, null);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        viewHolder.txtViewTitle.setText(itemsData[position].getTitle());
        viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(itemsData[position].getImageUrl());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemsData.length;
    }

}
```

Comment: Set the click listener inside your view holder. Define a listener interface and pass it first into the `Adapter` and then on to the `ViewHolder` in `onCreateViewHolder`. Handling clicks is actually done exactly the same way as in a `ListView`. Even before the `RecyclerView` you were not supposed to use the `OnItemClickListener` callbacks of the `ListView` which is why the `RecyclerView` does not have them at all anymore.

Answer (score 4):

The concept is well summed up by *Xaver Kapeller* in the comments. If you are looking for a simple way to manage your `RecyclerView` interaction similar to the traditional interactions of a `ListView`, check out [BigNerdRanch's recyclerview-multiselect](https://github.com/bignerdranch/recyclerview-multiselect) library on GitHub. They have a sample app that you can explore, which implements series of `OnClickListeners` and `OnLongClickListeners` with added capabilities of multi-selection.

Here's a snippet of how BigNerdRanch implements listeners in a `Fragment` across an `Adapter` and a `ViewHolder`, which in this case is actually an extension of the library's own `SwappingHolder.`

```
public CrimeHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView, mMultiSelector);

        mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_titleTextView);
        mDateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_dateTextView);
        mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_solvedCheckBox);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setLongClickable(true);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    public void bindCrime(Crime crime) {
        mCrime = crime;
        mTitleTextView.setText(crime.getTitle());
        mDateTextView.setText(crime.getDate().toString());
        mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(crime.isSolved());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (mCrime == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (!mMultiSelector.tapSelection(this)) {
            selectCrime(mCrime);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(mDeleteMode);
        mMultiSelector.setSelected(this, true);
        return true;
    }


}


private class CrimeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CrimeHolder> {
    @Override
    public CrimeHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int pos) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, parent, false);
        return new CrimeHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CrimeHolder holder, int pos) {
        Crime crime = mCrimes.get(pos);
        holder.bindCrime(crime);
        Log.d(TAG, "binding crime" + crime + "at position" + pos);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCrimes.size();
    }
}
```